# Retrieving a string value stored in an array that's stored in a JSON returns only the first character of the string

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js

I have this code here:

```
const timer = nodeSchedule.scheduleJob("*/5 * * * * *",function() {
    let arr = require("./autometar.json");
    for (let val in arr) {
        console.log(val);
        console.log(val[0]);
    }
});
```

`nodeSchedule` refers to an npm library called "node-schedule"; all it does in this context is run the function above every 5 seconds.

`autometar.json` is a file that current looks like this:

```
{
    "420431645041229834": [
        "422658075720417290",
        "KSEA",
        "KLAX"
    ],
    "test": [
        "this is a test"
    ]
}
```

Currently, I'm trying to retrieve the first value stored in the arrays stored within `autometar.json`. For example, I want to be able to retrieve the string `"this is a test"` from the array labeled as `"test"` in the file.

However, when running the function above with the given file, the console outputs the following:

```
420431645041229834
4
test
t
```

It appears to only be returning the first character of the strings stored, but I need the whole string.

Just for your information, this is running through Node.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close. Try this:

```
console.log(arr[val][0]);
```

`arr` is a JSON object and `val` is actually the key, not the value. `arr[val]` will give you the array you want, and then you can get the first item by using `arr[val][0]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the values of the object, Look:

```js
const sample = {
    "420431645041229834": [
        "422658075720417290",
        "KSEA",
        "KLAX"
    ],
    "test": [
        "this is a test"
    ]
}

Object.values(sample).forEach(value => {
   const [firstElementOfArray] = value
   console.log(firstElementOfArray)
})
```